# tile arrangement of images in UIScrollView or UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have an application like photo share in which i need to display images in tile view like GOOGLE IMAGE SEARCH.

Photos should be arranged in tile manner depending upon the size of an image
For better explanation i have attached example of google image search..

[image]

And

[image]

If you have any idea about this, Please share your knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the source code of an iOS library similar to what you are asking for. You can get the basic idea about how this can be done from the [Source Code](https://github.com/norsez/BDDynamicGridViewController).

Comment: this grid view is nice but in this gridview images are cropped as per the size. I want full images to be shown like google.

Comment: I said you can have a basic idea about the grid presentation. Frame size is what simply you can adjust as per your need right? I mean if you have a similar implementation, then you can easily change it.

Answer (score -1):

Use Scrollview.

Set two parameters, called xOffset and yOffset and UIScrollview *scrollView

```
int yOffset = 0;
int xOffset = 0;
for (int height=0; height < [y count]; height++)
{
    for (int width=0; width < [x count]; width++)
      {
          NSString *imageName = 
          UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
          UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
          imageView.frame = CGRectMake(xOffset, yOffset, imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height);
          [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
          xOffset += imageView.frame.size.width;
      }
   yOffset += imageView.frame.size.height;

}
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(xOffset,yOffset)];
```

Hope this helps...